# Git error: set remote passing token before pull or push

Tags: git, github

I'm having some problems with Github authentication. It's probably a stupid thing but I don't understand.

I have a personal access token with this scope:

[image]

When I need to clone a repo of my organization, I run:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/[organization]/[repo].git
```

I type my username and the token as password and the clone works.

Then, when I try to do a pull or a push, the CLI ask me the credential everytime.

If I use a software like Fork to pull, I get:

```
/usr/local/share/gcm-core/git-credential-manager-core get: /usr/local/share/gcm-core/git-credential-manager-core: No such file or directory
/usr/local/share/gcm-core/git-credential-manager-core erase: /usr/local/share/gcm-core/git-credential-manager-core: No such file or directory
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/accurat/edf-methanesat.git/'


In a case you entered incorrect password, please
update it in Keychain Access application.
```

To solve I have to run the following command for each new repo I need to clone:

```bash
git remote set-url origin https://[token]@github.com/[organization]/[repo].git
```

Is this the right way? Can I change some `git config` or stuff like that?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can clone the repo with the token in the URL to begin with:

```
git clone https://[token]@github.com/[organization]/[repo].git
```